# Line of best fit linear programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

i got this problem where i have to find the line of best fit to my linear programming problem. I got 2 sets of points where some of these points from each set cross over eachother, instead of them having their own two sides. I have to find the line that fits best to seperate these two sets with least points crossing their "side".

[image]

in the image i sent is a hint on where to start. I know i have to add a variable, but i dont understand how

Comment: This is not a Julia question. It's not even a programming question, really. Probably you're better off on the math, statistics, or economy SE.

Comment: Well it is, i have to draw this line using Julia

Comment: But that's a separate question. As stated, this one is only about the math problem. Once you got the, you can ask a separate one about the Julia implementation of the solution.