# Hyperplane separation of two sets of points (Julia)

Tags: julia, linear-programming, glpk

I have two sets of points (green and red) on a plane and the points are positioned in the way it's infeasible to find a line ax + by = 1 separating these two sets. So then I have to find the closest approximation of the line which excludes some points so it becomes feasible to draw the line (in other words. it is allowed to have some points on the other side). This is the code for separating two sets of points:

```
m = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
@variable(m, a[1:2])
@objective(m, Min, 0)

@constraint(m, [i=1:n], a[1]*green[i,1] + a[2]*green[i,2] <= 1) # n = number of points
@constraint(m, [i=1:n], a[1]*red[i,1] + a[2]*red[i,2] >= 1)
```

I'm stuck here. I guess I should add new variables in the constraints and make some changes in the objective function. What should I do?

Comment: The problem you ask for is a standard soft-margin linear SVM. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine you can find standard formulas you can use.

Comment: This question is oddly similar to this closed question from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971375/hyperplane-separation-of-two-sets-of-points-julia and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952193/line-of-best-fit-linear-programming. I would advise trying the Julia Discourse instead, but make sure not to violate any rules of academic integrity when asking there.

Comment: @NilsGudat Your first link is to *this* question.